# How to perform click on element that inside flexbox

Tags: python, selenium

I'm working on a web-scraping project , I encounter a problem that I couldn't locate the element(1H) by using `find_element_by_xpath/id/css-selector/class_name` and perform `click()`on it. Does anyone have any ideas how to make it work ? Thanks in advance!

Here's the part of my code

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from datetime import timedelta, date
import time
import datetime
import re
import mouse

def scrape(): 
    website = 'https://www.binance.com/en/trade-margin/BTC_USDT'
    path = '/Users/admin/Downloads/chromedriver'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
    driver.get(website) 
    driver.maximize_window()
    
    #click on 1H
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    one_hour = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="css-e2pgpg"][@id='1h']')
    actions.click(one_hour).perform()
```

Here's the html

```
#it is flexbox
<div class="css-e2pgpg">
<div id="Time" class="css-1pj8e72">Time</div>
<div id="15m" class="css-1pj8e72">15m</div>
<div id="1h" class="css-ktyfxp">1H</div> #i want to locate this element and perform click on it 
<div id="4h" class="css-1pj8e72">4H</div>
<div id="1d" class="css-1pj8e72">1D</div>
<div id="1w" class="css-1pj8e72">1W</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have to switch to the frame of the flexbox using `driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)` you can find [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/) the exact steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking to click on `1H web element`, you can do it by using the below code. We have to induce explicit wait to get the job done.

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get("https://www.binance.com/en/trade-margin/BTC_USDT")

try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='1H']"))).click()
    print("Clicked")
except:
    pass
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Sure do ! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I went to see the webpage myself. In my opinion, you don't have to locate the flexbox itself.

Just try with:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('1h').click();
```

Also, I would add some kind of wait until the page loads fully. You can use Thread.sleep, implicit waits or waiting for an element.

Comment: Thank you, it works , wait is essential and I complex the code

Comment: No problem, also, if you want to make the code a little cleaner and not have these long wait sausages, try using POM orientation. Good luck!

Comment: alright , Thanks man !